# The Blue Danube, by Johann Strauss

Tags: grammatical-case, gender, declension

This may be a silly question, I'm just a beginner. I read that the title in German of the work 'On the beautiful Blue Danube' is 'An der schönen, blauen Donau'. I'm not sure what is the article declension that works in this case, if it is an old usage of something, I'm confused about the gender and case of 'schönen' and 'blauen'. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to German.SE. CAn you describe what confuses you? What did you expect? (and please put your clarification via edit button into your question.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The adjectives *schönen* and *blauen*, as well as the definite article *der*, are all declined in the dative case, singular number, and feminine gender in agreement with Donau following the preposition *an* (“on”).